# What is the correct way of using --retain-symbol-file? when using the ld

Tags: c++, linker, ld

I want to use the linker flag --retain-symbols-file=filename but I am not getting the answer as expected.

This is my project where I am having two cpp files (File1.cpp, File2.cpp)

I am converting them into static libraries and merging them into a '.so' file.

```
//FileName: File1.hpp

void Func1();
```

```
//FileName: File1.cpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "File1.hpp"

void Func1 ()
{
    printf ("Inside Func1");
}
```

```
//FileName: File2.cpp

#include <stdio.h>

void Func2 ()
{
    printf ("Inside Func2");
}
```

Commands:

1. g++ -c File1.cpp
2. g++ -c File2.cpp
3. ar rcs File1.a File1.o
4. ar rcs File2.a File2.o
5. ld -shared -o result.so --retain-symbols-file=symbols.txt File1.a File2.a

If I try to now add one of the symbols in the text file then it doesn't get loaded in the .so file. Is this flag used for exporting a function as the '.def' file does in Windows? My understanding is that it should export this function. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

If I somehow reference/call these functions it where these are being called the symbols loaded by default but with the help of this linker flag all the symbols gets removed including those functions which I have mentioned in the text file.

Referencing: ld -shared -o result.so --retain-symbols-file=symbols.txt File1.a File2.a File3.o

```
//FileName: File3.cpp

#include "File1.hpp"
void Func3 ()
{
   Func1();
}
```

My Symbols.txt file is like this:

```
// FileName: Symbols.txt
Func1
```

Even this is referenced it doesn't come. Why this is happening? I am not able to understand. Can someone help me here?